# PyCharm smart indent not working?

Tags: django, pycharm

Perhaps I misunderstand what smart indent is.  When I type:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('some_model.views',
```

after pressing enter, would the next line not be a place one would expect a "smart indent"?  As it is now, the caret is placed without any indentation at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the answer would have to be that the smart indent is inconsistent at this point.

Answer (score 1):

The smart indent happens when you've provided the closing parenthesis, i.e.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('some_model.views', 
)
# if you press 'enter' after the comma, the newline will be indented.
```

That being said, if you're using **autocomplete** normally you should get `patterns()` with the both parenthesis automatically. The caret will be inside the parenthesis thus giving you the "smart indent" by default when you press `enter`.

Note that this is also the case when you work with dictionaries or lists in python. The auto-indent will not activate unless you also have the closing `}` or `]` for your dictionary/list respectively.

Comment: This is odd, because I _do_ have autocomplete on and I'm _not_ getting smart indent in the above scenario.  This works in your setup?

Comment: Do you have smart indent enabled in your settings? Go into settings --> Editor --> Smart Keys. See if the checkbox for smart indent is checked.